# jQuery to get hidden value of the corresponding checkbox checked true in MVC Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**My Requirement**

Using jQuery I need to get the value(`signalID`) at a hidden input for its corresponding checkbox checked true.

My View is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left checkboxtext signalCheckBox">
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.SelectSignalList.Count(); i++)
    {
        
        <li style="vertical-align:central; padding:-5px;">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SelectSignalList[i].IsSelected, new { @class = "checkboxsel"})
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectSignalList[i].SignalName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectSignalList[i].SignalID, new { @class = "checkboxID" })
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SelectSignalList[i].SignalName, new { @class = "checkboxtext" })
        </li>
       
    }
</ul>
```

Here I need to get all the SignalIDs (with class = CheckboxID) into an array, if its corresponding checkboxes (with class = checkboxsel) checked true.

So if the displayed checkboxes as

> S1(checked)  S2(not Checked) S3(checked)  S4(checked) S5(not Checked)

then only the IDs corresponding to the checkboxes `S1, S3 and S4` should be pushed to the array.

**What I have tried**

Below query I do not know how to get the index at `???` in my code here for getting the right id (`selected_value.push($(".checkboxID")[???].defaultValue);` )

```
$(".checkboxsel:checked").each(function () {
                    var item = $(this);   
                    selected_value.push($(".checkboxID")[???].defaultValue); 
                });
                sig = selected_value.toString();
```

If I place `i`, it pushes the subsequent IDs (0,1,2...) at hidden input for signalID and not taking the exact index at the index of the checkbox thats checked true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to refer to parent element then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to get the reference to `hidden` input.

Afterwards [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method can be used to gets elements properties.

*Use*

```
selected_value.push($(this).parent().find(".checkboxID").prop("defaultValue"));
```

*or*, use [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to get all following sibling with specific class.

```
selected_value.push($(this).nextAll(".checkboxID").prop("defaultValue"));
```